# How to fix Windows XP's extremely sharp fonts?

Tags: windows-xp, fonts, cleartype

I'm on a Mac, but I need to work with Visual Studio, so I run WinXP with Parallels.

Windows 7 is to heavy for my Mac Mini. Compared to Windows 7 And Mac OS X, WinXP has terrible fonts. They are extremely sharp, and eyes start hurting.

Is there a way to make them smooth? I heard about ClearType, but never managed to activate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes...ClearType is exactly what you need...but I prefer sharp text...well...here's a page for you

http://www.microsoft.com/typography/cleartype/tuner/step1.aspx

Comment: Interesting... I tried the very same page with no success. I'll try again. Must have done something wrong.

Comment: @Alex: I think it only works in Internet Explorer. There is also [ClearType Tuner PowerToy](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/cleartypepowertoy.mspx), a Control Panel applet.

Answer (score 2):

ClearType is good, but if you prefer the Mac style of font smoothing, [GDI++](http://cobyx.com/software/gdi/) is a closer approximation.

Comment: The "before" in the Google search is completely exaggerated.